# Does scanCharactersFromSet:intoString: create an autoreleased string?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscanner

While using Instruments, it seems like there is a leak coming from this method (`scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:`). I am not releasing the variable that gets put into `intoString`

Does this method create a retained or an autoreleased string in the `intoString` part of the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1), **you don’t own objects returned by reference**. Therefore, you must not release them.

The leak must be elsewhere.